# Word VBA Macro - Center+bold+caps first line of text

Tags: vba, macros, ms-word

I am trying to center the first line of text on a document, which would usually be the title.

I am able to center the line with

```
    Selection.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

But I am not sure how it is selecting the file line, as I would also like to set the title to bold and caps.

```
Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
Selection.Font.AllCaps = True
```

_

Also is there a way to "detect" any text that is centered already and has an empty space(line) above and below it, or would that be too difficult to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a with statement to apply multiple formats. Here is an example:

```
With Selection
.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
.Font.Bold = wdToggle
.Font.AllCaps = True
End With
```

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. I'm trying to figure out why it does not select the any text that is already centered, as I'd like to change that.
Would this not select any center aligned text? - `Selection.Find.Style = wdAlignParagraphCenter`

Comment: @Bp944 If I were you, I would open up a new distinct question about iterating through a word document to not select centered text. You may have received a downvote from someone because you asked 2 questions within one question. However, with the "With" method in place which I have provided, will make iteration formatting easier.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll go ahead and make a new post.